# SQL Server - How to convert the first next char to uppercase after the '/' sign

Tags: sql-server

I have a question on how to convert the first next char to uppercase after the '/' sign in the string.

As an example :

`CustomerName` : `ramayanan s/o vicky ratnam`

First i need it in the propercase, so i use this :

```
Update
dbo.table set CustomerName = dbo.ProperCase(CustomerName)
```

---

result : `Ramayanan S/o Vicky Ratnam`

but i need it to be as : `Ramayanan S/O Vicky Ratnam` (the first char after the `/` should be in `uppercase`)

Comment: if you can privide the code of propercase function than it will b lot easier..to help u

Comment: `Update dbo.table set CustomerName = replace( dbo.ProperCase(CustomerName),'/o', '/O')`

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE dbo.[table]
SET CustomerName = REPLACE(ProperCase(CustomerName),
                           SUBSTRING(CustomerName, CHARINDEX('/',CustomerName),2),
                           UPPER(SUBSTRING(CustomerName, CHARINDEX('/',CustomerName),2)))
WHERE CHARINDEX('/',CustomerName) > 0;
```

Searches for the fist `/` and replaces the `/` and the following character with `/` and the following character as upper case.

Comment: @user2376344:  +1 with the edit to fix the syntactic errors that kept it from executing originally.  I backed off as soon as I saw this answer pop up because it is good...but also found that it needed a little massaging on lines 1 and 4.  It now tests well on my box.

Comment: i'm sorry, so what is the full code now ? i try to apply this but a lot of CustomerName which do not have '/' also got affected as like John MuRray

Comment: @user2376344 I've added a where clause so that only values which actually contain a `/` are affected.

Answer (score 1):

Please check:

```
declare @T table(Insurance varchar(max))

insert into @T values ('roeselare')
insert into @T values ('BRUGGE')
insert into @T values ('ramayanan s/o vicky ratnam')

select (
       select upper(T.N.value('.', 'char(1)'))+
                lower(stuff(T.N.value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, ''))+(CASE WHEN RIGHT(T.N.value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1)='/' THEN '' ELSE ' ' END)
       from X.InsXML.nodes('/N') as T(N)
       for xml path(''), type
       ).value('.', 'varchar(max)') as Insurance
from 
  (
  select cast('<N>'+replace(
            replace(
                Insurance, 
                '/', '/</N><N>'),
            ' ', '</N><N>')+'</N>' as xml) as InsXML
  from @T
  ) as X
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Update dbo.table set CustomerName = REPLACE(CustomerName ,'/o','/O')
```

Comment: Hi Amit, thanks for the response, but i would like to make it as dynamic , instead of limit that to only S/O because we also have alot more like A/L D/O A/P and etc.   So after the '/' the very first char after that dynamically will be converted to uppercase

Comment: Without `table` in square brackets (i.e. `[table]`), you will get "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'table'."

Answer (score 0):

```
    Drop Table #Temp
    Create Table #Temp
    (
    CustomerName varchar(100)
    ) 

    Insert into #Temp
    values('Ramayanan S/o vicky ratnam')

    Select * from #temp

    Select  UPPER(SUBSTRING(CustomerName, CHARINDEX('/',CustomerName),2)),REPLACE( CustomerName ,
                               SUBSTRING(CustomerName, CHARINDEX('/',CustomerName),2),
                               UPPER(SUBSTRING(CustomerName, CHARINDEX('/',CustomerName),2))) from #temp


    UPDATE dbo.#Temp
    SET CustomerName = REPLACE( CustomerName ,
                               SUBSTRING(CustomerName, CHARINDEX('/',CustomerName),2),
                               UPPER(SUBSTRING(CustomerName, CHARINDEX('/',CustomerName),2))); 

     Select * from #temp
```